# How to update information without duplicating in the database

Tags: php, laravel

I'm still new to Laravel and I needed some help.
I have a job from a programming course that I'm stuck on, which is to import a .csv file like in the image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSRF9.png)

And I need to add it to the database without duplicating the CPF information as in the image:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzLH9.png)
*The information is merely illustrative.

So if anyone can help me I would appreciate it.

I can use updateOrCreate but it doesn't get the rest of the information.

Import:

```
public function collection(Collection $collection)
{
    foreach ($collection as $row) {

        Clientes::updateOrCreate(
            [   'cpf'       => $row[1]],
            [   'nome'      => $row[2],
                'telefone1' => $row[0],
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public function import(Request $request)
{
    $import = (new ImportTelefones(2));
    Excel::import($import, $request->file);

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Comment: please add some codes so we can know what you have tried and where you stuck

Comment: I added parts of the code. Does it help yet?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that you are trying to import an Excel or CSV file.

The easiest option for that is to use Laravel-Excel Package.

See here:

- Installation: https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/getting-started/installation.html
- Import: https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/

With that you should be able to import your file and have the data in the database.

To prevent duplicates you can use the 'upsert' feature. It will update the entry on import instead of creating it, if the configured unique key exists.

- https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/model.html#upserting-models

Best regards
Sergej